# Top clause in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

Data:

```
User ID       | plan           | effective date.  |  package
1.            | P1             |  24-05-2017      |  2017
1.            | P1             |  01-06-2017      |  2017
1.            | P2             |  01-07 2017      |  2017
```

If plan changes - select plan most recent effective date
In above case: I get it by top clause order by date desc

If plan does not change, both are p1 rows, suppose only first 2 rows are there, I have to select 25-05-2017 date row.

Trying to check previous year plan is same or not with last row.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want the most recent package for each user. If you want the most recent package for each user | plan combo, just add `plan` to the `partition by`... making it `(partition by [User ID], plan order by [effective date] desc)`

```
select
    [User ID]
    ,[plan]
    ,[effective date]
    ,[package] 
from
    (select 
        [User ID]
        ,[plan]
        ,[effective date]
        ,[package]
        ,row_number() over (partition by [User ID] order by [effective date] dec) as rn
     from YourTable) a
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use query as below:

```
Select top (1) with ties * from yourtable
order by row_number() over (partition by [user id] order by [effective date] desc)
```